# How to set all values except the row maximum to 0 in every row of a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, replace, network-analysis

Still a bit new to R and would appreciate some guidance. I have produced a relatedness matrix but before I melt it to create my edge list, I want to set all the values in each row to 0 EXCEPT for the row maximum. Any tips on how to do this?

I have no idea what to try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` + `replace`:

```r
m <- matrix(1:9, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

t(apply(m, 1, function(x) replace(x, x != max(x), 0)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    7
[2,]    0    0    8
[3,]    0    0    9
```

or with `tapply`:

```r
do.call(rbind, tapply(m, row(m), function(x) replace(x, x != max(x), 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks but this code doesnt work for me - I end up with a matrix mostly full of 0s and where a few values have remained, they're all in one of 3 columns (out of 100). There are rows with only 0s now.

Answer (score 0):

`max.col` will be useful here:

```
m <- matrix(sample(100), 10, 10)
m
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]   93   78   98   14   11   74   63    5   38    43
#>  [2,]   34    1   55   64   67   15   97   37    4    89
#>  [3,]   52   25   75   20   77   28   65   84   39    49
#>  [4,]    3   45   79   50   18   60   48   16   13    42
#>  [5,]   24   69   91   44    9   87   17   62    2    32
#>  [6,]   95   94   68   53   99   70   82   36   66    40
#>  [7,]   92   41   23   54   30   21   88   81   72    83
#>  [8,]   59  100   56   27   10   46    6   12   26    19
#>  [9,]   90   35   71   51    8   86   76   29   31    96
#> [10,]   58   33   47   73   85   61   80   57    7    22
m[-(1:nrow(m) + (max.col(m) - 1L)*ncol(m))] <- 0
m
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    0    0   98    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0   97    0    0     0
#>  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   84    0     0
#>  [4,]    0    0   79    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [5,]    0    0   91    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [6,]    0    0    0    0   99    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [7,]   92    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [8,]    0  100    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    96
#> [10,]    0    0    0    0   85    0    0    0    0     0
```

With a `numeric` matrix with named rows/columns:

```
m <- matrix(runif(100), 10, 10, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:10], LETTERS[11:20]))
m
#>           K          L          M         N         O         P          Q         R          S          T
#> A 0.8455340 0.97713257 0.89784675 0.9116978 0.5132513 0.4197610 0.39154932 0.5499533 0.74761367 0.04024061
#> B 0.2574573 0.42892093 0.55113837 0.1347042 0.9728912 0.2104251 0.51084878 0.6308227 0.08114070 0.08541959
#> C 0.3393108 0.14198061 0.12190379 0.2433768 0.1043313 0.2526678 0.21550723 0.5086210 0.07906360 0.88046001
#> D 0.1492551 0.66689551 0.04958598 0.3519842 0.2420030 0.5919464 0.27392652 0.2029944 0.32210388 0.90704707
#> E 0.4473961 0.61912114 0.58880869 0.9073496 0.7760235 0.7955465 0.43140215 0.5572331 0.32165581 0.90433083
#> F 0.0279498 0.86375368 0.35372818 0.5033064 0.4016708 0.6530612 0.18887117 0.3123320 0.03582699 0.27059191
#> G 0.1848169 0.11436509 0.84722483 0.8874162 0.2558677 0.6839403 0.85603179 0.5178988 0.53953932 0.55142390
#> H 0.1056349 0.48193774 0.44023254 0.5574092 0.9154315 0.6261866 0.51314697 0.5838974 0.92684901 0.75310930
#> I 0.9220023 0.86660126 0.87581045 0.2354375 0.9385472 0.3527555 0.09545731 0.1028695 0.99012272 0.71308235
#> J 0.9915948 0.04529849 0.40984050 0.4431233 0.8482269 0.1817989 0.73221712 0.6340093 0.68836208 0.69083152
m[-(1:nrow(m) + (max.col(m) - 1L)*ncol(m))] <- 0
m
#>           K         L M         N         O P Q R         S         T
#> A 0.0000000 0.9771326 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0 0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> B 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.9728912 0 0 0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> C 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0 0 0.0000000 0.8804600
#> D 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0 0 0.0000000 0.9070471
#> E 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0.9073496 0.0000000 0 0 0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> F 0.0000000 0.8637537 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0 0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> G 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0.8874162 0.0000000 0 0 0 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> H 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0 0 0.9268490 0.0000000
#> I 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0 0 0.9901227 0.0000000
#> J 0.9915948 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0 0 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: Your example code works for me but when I try to sub in my matrix, it doesn't. Could this be because (a) my matrix has row names and column names, or (b) the values in my matrix have decimals (not whole numbers)?

Comment: No. See the updated answer. What doesn't work? Are you getting an error or unexpected results? Try updating the question with a minimum reproducible example.